# How to restrict access to website information if the browser is not correct?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, browser, cross-browser

Is there a possibility to restrict access to the information and data on a website if the user is not using a specific web browser?
Want to develop a web browser that can view only one website. I am developing an NFT marketplace and for security reasons, I want to fuse a website and a web browser in one.
Didn't see anyone do this before.
Is it possible to restrict it with javascript and/or jquery?

Comment: "_I want to fuse a website and a web browser in one_" - Sounds like [Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/electron/info). However if you are doing this "_for security reasons_", you should hire a security expert to check if this actually makes and how to best achieve it.

Comment: I would not rely on user side scripts (JavaScript or JQuery) for any security. You may want to reconsider your approach. After all, I can defeat whatever you do by turning Javascript off in my browser. Also, your question is rather broad and may lead to opinion answers rather than fact-based answers. There is a very good chance this question will be closed. This really does sound like a server-side problem to me though.

Comment: @Ivar I think that Electron wouldn't solve the problem. Thanks anyway for your reply.

Comment: @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt I expected that I would receive an answer like this. I thought that there was the possibility to achieve it on the user side. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Yes it is certainly possible to hardcode a browser that you are creating yourself so that it can only work for a single website... _how_ to do that is too broad a question for Stack Overflow, however. First you need to build the browser, and then show us the code you have for checking the website. The implementation will depend on whether you are checking the URL, the IP address, if there will be any attempt at checking for redirect voodoo, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the UserAgent header, or `navigator.userAgent` in JavaScript. This is only for user convenience though, not security, as a user can change their UserAgent to anything they want.